# Django-allauth - if a user is already logged in with twitter/google+/facebook, how will he be able to get logged in automatically in my website?

Tags: python, django, facebook, google-plus, django-allauth

I'm using **django-allauth** for my social account login. After the user completes registration, he gets logged in.

On another day, the user is already logged in with twitter/google+/facebook. How will he be able to get logged in automatically in my website?

Is there anyway, I can accomplish this preferably by a configuration setting.

Note: I'm not using email verification.

Comment: Is it cookies what you want?

Comment: How to accomplish this using cookies?